# Packaging PySpark with PEX environment on dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc, python-pex

I'm trying to package a pyspark job with PEX to be run on google cloud dataproc, but I'm getting a `Permission Denied` error.

I've packaged my third party and local dependencies into `env.pex` and an entrypoint that uses those dependencies into `main.py`. I then `gsutil cp` those two files up to `gs://<PATH>` and run the script below.

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1 as dataproc
from google.cloud import storage

def submit_job(project_id: str, region: str, cluster_name: str):
    job_client = dataproc.JobControllerClient(
        client_options={"api_endpoint": f"{region}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443"}
    )
    operation = job_client.submit_job_as_operation(
        request={
            "project_id": project_id,
            "region": region,
            "job": {
                "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
                "pyspark_job": {
                    "main_python_file_uri": "gs://<PATH>/main.py",
                    "file_uris": ["gs://<PATH>/env.pex"],
                    "properties": {
                        "spark.pyspark.python": "./env.pex",
                        "spark.executorEnv.PEX_ROOT": "./.pex",
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    )
```

The error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./env.pex": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 14 more
```

Should I expect packaging my environment like this to work? I don't see a way to change the permission of files included as `file_uris` in the pyspark job config, and I don't see any documentation on google cloud about packaging with PEX, but [PySpark official docs include this guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html#using-pex).

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to run the pex directly in the end, but did get a workaround working for now, which was suggested by a user in the [pants slack community](https://www.pantsbuild.org/docs/getting-help) (thanks!)...

The workaround is to unpack the pex as a venv in a cluster initialization script.

The initialization script gsutil copied to `gs://<PATH TO INIT SCRIPT>`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -exo pipefail

readonly PEX_ENV_FILE_URI=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/PEX_ENV_FILE_URI || true)
readonly PEX_FILES_DIR="/pexfiles"
readonly PEX_ENV_DIR="/pexenvs"

function err() {
    echo "[$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')]: $*" >&2
    exit 1
}

function install_pex_into_venv() {
    local -r pex_name=${PEX_ENV_FILE_URI##*/}
    local -r pex_file="${PEX_FILES_DIR}/${pex_name}"
    local -r pex_venv="${PEX_ENV_DIR}/${pex_name}"

    echo "Installing pex from ${pex_file} into venv ${pex_venv}..."
    gsutil cp "${PEX_ENV_FILE_URI}" "${pex_file}"
    PEX_TOOLS=1 python "${pex_file}" venv --compile "${pex_venv}"
}

function main() {
    if [[ -z "${PEX_ENV_FILE_URI}" ]]; then
        err "ERROR: Must specify PEX_ENV_FILE_URI metadata key"
    fi

    install_pex_into_venv
}

main
```

To start the cluster and run the initialization script to unpack the pex into a venv on the cluster:

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1 as dataproc

def start_cluster(project_id: str, region: str, cluster_name: str):
    cluster_client = dataproc.ClusterControllerClient(...)
    operation = cluster_client.create_cluster(
        request={
            "project_id": project_id,
            "region": region,
            "cluster": {
                "project_id": project_id,
                "cluster_name": cluster_name,
                "config": {
                    "master_config": <CONFIG>,
                    "worker_config": <CONFIG>,
                    "initialization_actions": [
                        {
                            "executable_file": "gs://<PATH TO INIT SCRIPT>",
                        },
                    ],
                    "gce_cluster_config": {
                        "metadata": {"PEX_ENV_FILE_URI": "gs://<PATH>/env.pex"},
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    )
```

To start the job and use the unpacked pex venv to run the pyspark job:

```
def submit_job(project_id: str, region: str, cluster_name: str):
    job_client = dataproc.ClusterControllerClient(...)
    operation = job_client.submit_job_as_operation(
        request={
            "project_id": project_id,
            "region": region,
            "job": {
                "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
                "pyspark_job": {
                    "main_python_file_uri": "gs://<PATH>/main.py",
                    "properties": {
                        "spark.pyspark.python": "/pexenvs/env.pex/bin/python",
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a PEX file using a compatible interpreter. So instead of specifying a program of `./env.pex` you could try `python env.pex`. That does not require `env.pex` to be executable.

Comment: Doing this appears to be impossible with dataproc / pyspark, since the property `spark.pyspark.python` requires a single value that is an existing (executable) program, no arguments are allowed to follow it and there is no way to specify arguments separately.

Answer (score 1):

Following @megabits answer here is the bash based workflow that works for me

1. copy the init script (from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840903/392083)) to GCS as `gs://BUCKET/pkg/cluster-env-init.bash`
2. build PEX providing `--include-tools` argument that is required by initialization script, e.g.

```
pex --include-tools -r requirements.txt -o env.pex
```

3. put PEX file on GCS

```
gsutil mv env.pex "gs://BUCKET/pkg/env.pex"
```

4. create cluster using PEX file to set-up env

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create your-cluster --region us-central1 \
  --initialization-actions="gs://BUCKET/pkg/cluster-env-init.bash" \
  --metadata "PEX_ENV_FILE_URI=gs://BUCKET/pkg/env.pex"
```

5. run job

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark your-script.py \
  --cluster=your-cluster --region us-central1 \
  --properties spark.pyspark.python="/pexenvs/env.pex/bin/python"
```